# HTML form won't validate in IE9

Tags: jquery, html

Here's a simple HTML form that works and validates properly on Firefox and Chrome, but it does not on IE9. On IE, when you repeatedly press the submit button without entering any input, the validation message prints repeatedly on the screen.

When I switch IE to compatibilty mode, no validation message prints and nothing happens :(

Here's the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function() {         

             $("#contactform").validate({
                rules: {
                firstname   : "required",
                surname     : "required", 
                emessage    : "required",
                pcode1      : "required",               
                phone       : "required",
                cname       : "required",

              email: {                // compound rule
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    }            
             },
                messages: {             
                   firstname : " *Required",                
                   surname   : " *Required",    
                   email     : " *Required",
                   emessage  : " *Required",    
                   pcode1    : " *Required",
                   phone     : " *Required",
                   cname     : " *Required",
              }
            });                             

        });     

    </script>
<title>Example</title>


</head>
<body>

<p>
<form id="contactform" method="post" action="email.php" class="form">
      <table>
       <tr>
           <td>
                Name*
           </td>
           <td>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
                Surname*
           </td>
           <td>
                <input type="text" name="surname" id="surname">
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
                Company name*
           </td>
           <td>
                <input type="text" name="cname" id="cname">
           </td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
           <td>
                Email*
           </td>
           <td>
                <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
           </td>
       </tr>


       <tr>
           <td>
                Telephone*
           </td>
           <td>
                <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone">
           </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
           <td>
                Postcode*
           </td>
           <td>
                <input type="text" name="pcode1" id="pcode1" size="" maxlength="8">
           </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
           <td>
                Message*
           </td>

           <td>
                 <textarea id="emassage" name="emessage" cols="67" rows="6"></textarea>
           </td>
       </tr>

        <tr>
           <td>
                <button name="submit" id="submit" class="shiny-blue">Submit</button>

           </td>

           <td>

           </td>
       </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</p>

</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you verify that the code runs? Any exceptions in the console, 404s, etc?

Comment: Stupid question, but is this HTML or XHTML? (I mean, the DOCTYPE says XHTML, but the http-equiv meta says HTML.) Now since IE9 is the first IE that can actually tell those apart, maybe it gets confused. Older IE's won't get confused, as they don't know about XHTML.

Comment: Also, not all `id` attributes match the `name` attributes on the controls. The textarea for instance has id="emassage" but name="emessage". I don't know if this matters; can't test here.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will check if the XHTML/HTML tag may be the issue and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

According to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=form-validation), IE9 doesn't support HTML form validation.